Is there any way to use shell variable in postinst in Debian package
I've developed a Debian package and built it into a test.deb file. In the postinst script of this package, I'm trying to use a variable $MY_APP_HTTP_PORT as follows:
if [ -n "$MY_APP_HTTP_PORT" ]; then 
  echo "MY_APP_HTTP_PORT=$MY_APP_HTTP_PORT" >> /root/test.env
fi

However, when I install the test.deb package and set the MY_APP_HTTP_PORT variable in the shell environment like this:
export MY_APP_HTTP_PORT=1080
apt install ./test.deb

The if condition in the postinst script doesn't work because $MY_APP_HTTP_PORT doesn't seem to be set by the shell during installation. How can I properly set and use the MY_APP_HTTP_PORT variable in the postinst script of a Debian package during installation?

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103905/7939871

This seems like an XY problem. There is no useful way you can run the postinst script as your own user from within the installation process. What are you actually hoping to achieve? To enable or disable particular behavior, probably use a debconf variable.
